# Convexity adjustment

Tags: fixed-income, swaps

I have a problem with the underlying assumption in the future/forward convexity adjustment.
If I understand correctly, the assumption is, if I am long ED, I earn money when rates go down and invest the money in a lower rate and vice versa.
What I don't agree with is that the correlation between the spot rate and for example EDU5 is very far from 1, sometimes it is even negative (especially in a crisis).
So I may earn money on long EDU5 and invest the earnings in a higher rate, as the spot rate is going high as well.

1. Do most models assume 1 correlation between the spot rate and the forward rate?
2. Any models thay take the correlation under consideration?

Comment: My thoughts are that I am missing a concrete question.

Comment: I guess the question is "why is the standard convexity adjustment wrong according to current market rates?"

Comment: I'am afraid that all the models for convexity adjustements I have seen state these values are correlated. This is a common case where models differ from market datas.

Comment: I think it is not the aim of this community to "guess questions" ...voting to close.

Comment: ok, my question has 2 parts:

Comment: 1. (Did I understand correctly, and) does most models assume 1 correlation between the spot rate and the forward rate?

Comment: 2. Any models thayt take the correlation under consideration? if it is not 1

Comment: @user5726: edit your question instead of posting comments.

Comment: most models assume positive correlation, not 1. I would suggest you to take a look at how convexity adjustement is theoretically builmt.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Since convexity adjustments are somewhat soup du jour, I've done this for him/her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have traded those convexity adjustments for many years.  Any decent model of these adjustments allows the user to vary the correlation as they please, rather than assuming something.  If it is of interest, the implied correlations usually trade significantly under 1, especially in periods when the curve is volatile.  ie when forward rates might be going in different direction to the short end.